# How to create a folder that contains the current date and time instead of name

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I use C++ Windows Form application in Visual Studio 2013 for one project.
I wonder how to create a folder that contains the current date and time instead of name? It is possible to make such folder??

```
DirectoryInfo^ directory = Directory::CreateDirectory("C:\Users\Desktop\" + ??);
```

Comment: Create the string dynamically, then you can format it in any way you like. Also remember that even in the Microsoft-extended versions of C++, the backslash (\\) character have special meaning inside character and string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't hard-code the desktop directory name, it is not c:\users\desktop.  .NET makes it easy:

```
String^ path = System::IO::Path::Combine(
    Environment::GetFolderPath(System::Environment::SpecialFolder::Desktop),
    DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"));
System::IO::Directory::CreateDirectory(path);
// Write file(s) to <path>
//...
```

It is up to you to decide how fine-grained to make the directory name, if you do this at a very high rate then you must append "fff" to reduce the risk for name collisions.  If it is a once-a-week task then just the date part is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
        time_t currentTime;
        struct tm *localTime;

        time(&currentTime);
        localTime = localtime(&currentTime);
        int Day = localTime->tm_mday;
        int Month = localTime->tm_mon + 1;
        int Year = localTime->tm_year + 1900;
        int Hour = localTime->tm_hour;
        int Min = localTime->tm_min;
        int Sec = localTime->tm_sec;

        String^ dateTime = Day.ToString() + "." + Month.ToString() + "." + Year.ToString() + " (" + Hour.ToString() + "." + Min.ToString() + "." + Sec.ToString() + ")";

        DirectoryInfo^ directoryR = Directory::CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\" + dateTime);
```